# how to add array in variable and send it in url by get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send multiple values in one parameter

```
// from client side will be like
var x= [1,2,3]
```

after sending the parameters, how to retrieve it the like this

```
def func1()
    y=params[:x] // [1,2,3]
    .....
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can send the parameters like this

```
http://url?x[]=1&x[]=2&x[]=3
```

and will receive the parameter as an array in the backend

```
arr = params[:x] /// [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not very clear I assume you are asking about sending parameters using a `form`

In view,

```
= text_field_tag 'array_field', '1,2,3,4,5'
```

In controller,

```
params[:array_field].split(',')
#=> ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

Tried this example in console

```
irb > "1,2,3".split(',')
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Hope that helps!